# I am trying to code a discord music bot and came with this problem

Tags: discord.py, youtube-dl, pynacl

my problem are the packages are the tags one

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmrvl.png)

the main.py code

````
from discord.ext import commands
import music

cogs = [music]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='sus!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

for i in range(len(cogs)):
    cogs[i].setup(client)


client.run("The discord bot id")```
````

Answer (score 1):

So error seems to be ur syntax error in ur `music.py` line 2 make `from discord.ext import commands`

If it works , pls make this answer as accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

So it seems you forgot to import discord... do
`import discord  from discord.ext import commands`

this is definetly gonna fix your problem but remember you can't take something from something that you haven't imported. Just like you can't take something from discord.ext if you haven't imported discord since discord.ext is extension and you haven't even imported discord.